# e4defrag - what does output mean?

Tags: ext4, defrag

e4defrag shows many lines like `(filename)  100% [ OK ]` or `(filename) 0% [ NG ]`, and at finish shows success/failures.

Does NG mean it was not moved, OK means it was defragmented? What are the failures?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at its [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/e4defrag.8.html) and running the program on a directory, the program seems to do nothing on files with a low fragmentation count. It is recommended to calculate the fragmentation count by running the program with the `-c` option.

`[ NG ]` is the opposite of `[ OK ]` and stands for not good. You need to run the program with the `-v` option, it should then show you the fragmentation count before and after defrag as well as one of the following error [messages form the source code](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/misc/e4defrag.c) in the event of an NG status:

```
#define NGMSG_EXT4          "Filesystem is not ext4 filesystem"
#define NGMSG_FILE_EXTENT   "Failed to get file extents"
#define NGMSG_FILE_INFO     "Failed to get file information"
#define NGMSG_FILE_OPEN     "Failed to open"
#define NGMSG_FILE_UNREG    "File is not regular file"
#define NGMSG_LOST_FOUND    "Can not process \"lost+found\""
```