# Output of e4defrag

Tags: command-line, filesystem, ext4, defrag

`e4defrag` - the only defragmentation tool I know for Linux - outputs a lot of information not covered by its manual.  I assume that if a command outputs something, it is important thus I would like to understand the output.

Here is exemplary outputs (without superuser privileges and verbosity):

```
$ e4defrag defrag/
e4defrag 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext4 defragmentation for directory(defrag/)
[2/3]/*/defrag/986M.file:   100%    [ OK ]
[3/3]/*/defrag/986M.file2:  100%    [ OK ]

    Success:            [ 2/3 ]
    Failure:            [ 1/3 ]
```

100% I guess means that `e4defrag` defragmented the whole file, *OK* means the file is defragmented, *Success 2/3* is number of _OK_s, but what the Failure is?  Should I be worried about it or not?

When I ask for more verbosity I get:

```
e4defrag -v defrag/
e4defrag 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext4 defragmentation for directory(defrag/)
[1/3] "/*/defrag"
    File is not regular file        [ NG ]
[2/3]/*/defrag/986M.file:   100%  extents: 1 -> 1   [ OK ]
[3/3]/*/defrag/986M.file2:  100%  extents: 3 -> 3   [ OK ]

    Success:            [ 2/3 ]
    Failure:            [ 1/3 ]
    Total extents:             4->4
    Fragmented percentage:       50%->50%
```

I can see that the *defrag* directory, as not a regular file, failed to be defragmented, but why is it Not Good (*NG*: [e4defrag - what does output mean?](https://askubuntu.com/a/324760/633655))?
Both regular files are identical, but one is written as 1 extent, while the other as 3.  Why does it count as success when `e4defrag` clearly failed to defragment it?
What is the *Fragmented percentage*? Percentage of fragmented files? Percentage of excessive extents?

But it starts to be really confusing when I run the command as root in `-c` mode:

```
# e4defrag -c defrag/
e4defrag 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
<Fragmented files>                             now/best       size/ext
1. /*/defrag/986M.file2
                                                 3/1         336408 KB
2. /*/defrag/986M.file
                                                 1/1         1009224 KB

 Total/best extents             4/2
 Average size per extent            504612 KB
 Fragmentation score                0
 [0-30 no problem: 31-55 a little bit fragmented: 56- needs defrag]
 This directory (defrag/) does not need defragmentation.
 
 Done.
```

Now both files are listed as fragmented...  My guesses are wrong.  So, how should I interpret the output?

[EDIT]

I have just found that `e4defrag` counts files with more than one extent as fragmented, while it knows that the extents are contiguous:

```
$ sudo filefrag file.file
file.file: 1 extent found
$ sudo e4defrag -vc file.file
e4defrag 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
<File>
[ext 1]: start 22388736: logical 0: len 32768
[ext 2]: start 22421504: logical 32768: len 32768
[ext 3]: start 22454272: logical 65536: len 32768
[ext 4]: start 22487040: logical 98304: len 27962

 Total/best extents 4/1
 Average size per extent 126266 KB
 Fragmentation score 0
 [0-30 no problem: 31-55 a little bit fragmented: 56- needs defrag]
 This file (file.file) does not need defragmentation.
 Done.
```

Comment: Apparently, e4defrag does not strive to achieve 100% defragmantation rate. From `man e4defrag`: "If target is a directory, e4defrag reduces fragmentation of all files in it."

Comment: @mikewhatever it is not even interested in checking whether file is really fragmented or not. See my edit.